# xslt, calculating sum of sum using function

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have client invoices which I calculate price* quantity + total for this colum (for each invoice and each client) using the following function:
    
        Total

```
<xsl:template name="sumProducts"> 
    <xsl:param name="pList"/> 
    <xsl:param name="pRunningTotal" select="0"/>         
    <xsl:choose> 
       <xsl:when test="$pList"> 
           <xsl:variable name="varMapPath" select="$pList[1]"/> 
           <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts"> 
               <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="$pList[position() > 1]"/> 
                   <xsl:with-param name="pRunningTotal" select="$pRunningTotal + $varMapPath/unitprice *  $varMapPath/quantity"/>                    
           </xsl:call-template> 
       </xsl:when> 
       <xsl:otherwise> 
           $<xsl:value-of select="format-number($pRunningTotal, '#,##0.00')"/> 
       </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
```

I would like to calculate the total for all invoices per client and  total invoices for all clients.

Thank you

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide a source XML document(preferrably small), which is missing at present.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using recursive template I would use a variable. Take a look at this example where I calculate subtotal for each item and add it to the item. Then I use sum() function for calculating total:

Input xml:

```
<root>
  <items>
    <item price="19" quantity="12" />
    <item price="5" quantity="3" />
    <item price="4" quantity="1" />
    <item price="2" quantity="2" />
  </items>
</root>
```

Xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <root>
    <xsl:variable name="items-with-sub-totals">
      <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:attribute name="sub-total">
            <xsl:value-of select="@price * @quantity"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <debug>
      <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($items-with-sub-totals)/*"/>
    </debug>

      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Total:', sum(msxsl:node-set($items-with-sub-totals)/item/@sub-total))" />
    </root>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (I added some debug information to show how the variable looks like):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <debug>
    <item price="19" quantity="12" sub-total="228" />
    <item price="5" quantity="3" sub-total="15" />
    <item price="4" quantity="1" sub-total="4" />
    <item price="2" quantity="2" sub-total="4" />
  </debug>
  Total:251
</root>
```

This is a bit different approach than you are trying but hopefully will work for you

Comment: Hi Pawel Thank you for your time but the problem was not how to get the total (already done) but for this calculated total how to sum all invoices for all client.

Comment: If this is in one xml document then you can use the above (or your method) to calculate this. If you have multiple documents you can loop over them using document() function and transform. You would probably have to pass list of files to the stylesheet

Comment: How to calculate this using my method.

Comment: Show the input xml document and what you want to get.

Comment: see the following link for clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907129/how-to-calculate-sum-of-sum-using-recursive-function