# how to calculate sum of sum using recursive function

Tags: xml, xslt

I used recursive function to calculate the total of calculated column (price * quantity), for each invoice and each client. Now I need to calculate the total for all invoices per client and for all invoices for all clients.

xml looks like this:

```
  <cinvoices>
        <client> (with information @ client) </client>
            <invoices>
                <products>
                    <product> (information @ product: name, type ect and..
                        <price>123</price>
                        <quantity>21</quantity>
                    </product>
                    <product> (information @ product: name, type ect and..
                        <price>123</price>
                       <quantity>11</quantity>
                   </product>
                </products>
           <invoices>
               <products>
                    <product> (information @ product: name, type ect and..
                    <price>32</price>
                    <quantity>3</quantity>
               </product>
               <product> (information @ product: name, type ect and..
                    <price>12</price>
                    <quantity>9</quantity>
               </product>
           </products>
       </invoices>
    </client>
    <client>

      <same as above>
    </client>
    </cinvoices>
```

The function used in xslt is:

```
<xsl:template name="sumProducts"> 
        <xsl:param name="pList"/> 
        <xsl:param name="pRunningTotal" select="0"/>         
        <xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:when test="$pList"> 
                <xsl:variable name="varMapPath" select="$pList[1]"/> 
                <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts"> 
                    <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="$pList[position() > 1]"/> 
                    <xsl:with-param name="pRunningTotal" 
                    select="$pRunningTotal + $varMapPath/price *    $varMapPath/quantity"/>                    
                </xsl:call-template> 
            </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:otherwise> 
                $<xsl:value-of select="format-number($pRunningTotal, '#,##0.00')"/> 

            </xsl:otherwise>  

        </xsl:choose> 
              </xsl:template>
```

=====================
function called as follow:

```
  <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts"> 
                             <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="*/*"/> 
                             </xsl:call-template>
```

Any idea how to use this function to calculate the total for invoices for each client and the grand total for all clients and all invoices.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first rephrase your requirements.

The following template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="sumProducts">
        <xsl:param name="pList"/>
        <xsl:param name="pRunningTotal" select="0"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pList">
                <xsl:variable name="varMapPath" select="$pList[1]"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="$pList[position() > 1]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pRunningTotal" select="$pRunningTotal + $varMapPath/price *    $varMapPath/quantity"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise> 
                $<xsl:value-of select="format-number($pRunningTotal, '#,##0.00')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/cinvoices/client/invoices">
        <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
            <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="*/*"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to the following XML file:

```
<cinvoices>
    <client>
        <invoices>
            <products>
                <product>
                    <price>123</price>
                    <quantity>21</quantity>
                </product>
                <product>
                    <price>123</price>
                    <quantity>11</quantity>
                </product>
            </products>
        </invoices>
        <invoices>
            <products>
                <product>
                    <price>32</price>
                    <quantity>3</quantity>
                </product>
                <product>
                    <price>12</price>
                    <quantity>9</quantity>
                </product>
            </products>
        </invoices>
    </client>
    <client>
        <invoices>
            <products>
                <product>
                    <price>100</price>
                    <quantity>2</quantity>
                </product>
                <product>
                    <price>10</price>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                </product>
            </products>
        </invoices> 
    </client>
</cinvoices>
```

should produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
            $3,936.00 
            $204.00 
            $210.00
```

So these are values per invoice.

Your solution uses XSLT named template. This problem may solved using different techniques, but I will stick to the idea you already have.

Now, modify the last template with the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="/cinvoices/client">
    <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
        <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="*/*/*"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

You will get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
                $4,140.00 
                $210.00
```

These are the totals for all the invoices per client.

Now, modify the last template with this code:

```
<xsl:template match="/cinvoices">
    <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
        <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="*/*/*/*"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

And you will get the total for all clients:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
                $4,350.00
```

Comment: Thank you Lukasz for you time. I've already found the solution using the same principle. It solved the problem!

Comment: @FloreDraw great, so now you should either paste and accept your solution or simply accept mine :)

Comment: By using this template, how to calculate the average for each client type (client has type A or type B or type C). Also by using the same template how to calculate the 6 top incoices and the highest and lowest invoice for each category. thank you